# IISNode running Node.js with multiple domains issue

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I put a basic, no frills node npm-express blog site up on a azure website and the IIS load balancing or just iisnode itself seemed to cause issues running the app.js. Running outside of IIS didn't experience any issues. No websockets, just express using vash templates.

The issues I ran into are:
Using web deploy and some node_modules intermittently not deploying. npm lwip for instance would work at first then wouldn't if deploying again.  Sometimes other js and vash files would not update also.

When using the site there was a plain vash templates section (the public facing side) and a login side of the site. The simple one page public facing side would intermittently create a 500 error. One out of every three request would do this. No logs generated and all logging was turned on. The error was from iisnode and not node itself.

Using visual studio 13 with all the latest updates, remote debugging simply didn't work. Basically in the dark. Oddly the logged in portion using npm-passport-local worked but that never changed domains when using. It was only the pages on the public side that this would happen. FYI, the public side had multiple domains and various sub domains pointing to the site. All entered correctly in the azure portal and would work with the intermittent 500 error.  The page had links to other blogs with full urls, hence the domain would change. Which should be an issue but I suspect had something to do with it.

I ended up having to create a azure vm and install node on it myself to get the site working without the use of IIS. FYI, running the node site locally on my sand I never encountered any issues either.

Has anyone else experienced issues like this using iisnode and did you find a work around for this?
I suspect it may happen when multiple domains are used for the same instance.

Comment: Regarding Remote Debugging with Visual Studio, did you turn on Remote Debugging from your site's Configure tab and set Remote Debugging Visual Studio Version to 2013? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: It would be great if you can share your application (via github) that you tried to deploy on Azure Websites? I will try to deploy it myself and investigate issues if any.

Comment: Yes, remote debugging was turned on. It would attempt to connect and after a minute display a message "It is taking to long to connect". Tried it from two different machines on different networks and both would display that. The prototype is anzurs dot com and working on VM just fine. Something to do with load balancing I suspect. I prefer tfs online over git for visual studio.